# Cant able to set wrapper class value to lightning input text field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-community

apex class :

```
    public class quotewebservices {
   public static String language {get;set;}
   Public static  string  NicoPinFrance{get;set;}
   public static List<AccountDetails> AccountDetailsList {get;set;}      

@AuraEnabled
    public static List<AccountDetails> france(string NicoPinFrance){
   // public  static List<AccountDetails> InfoWithoutAccNum() {
        String XMLString;
        AccountDetailsList = new List<AccountDetails>();
       XMLString='<RESULT><PARTNUMBER>D221C04DXX-0005-3310</PARTNUMBER><DESCRIPTION>Boîtier série\'s 0F 12 pts</DESCRIPTION><DESCRIPTIONUK>housing serie\'s OF 12pts</DESCRIPTIONUK><STOCK>43382</STOCK><CLIENTPNS></CLIENTPNS></RESULT>';
                String PartNicomat='';
                String PartDescription= '';
                String PartDescriptionUK='';
                String PartStock='';
                String PartClientPNREF='';
        //Getting the values from xml String
      system.debug(XMLString);
      if(XMLString!=null){
          Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
            doc.load(XMLString);
            dom.XmlNode node=doc.getRootElement();
            //Condition to check the responce without error 
            if(node.getChildElements()[0].getName() != 'ERROR'){
                PartNicomat=node.getChildElement('PARTNUMBER',null).getText();
                PartDescription=  node.getChildElement('DESCRIPTION',null).getText();
                PartDescriptionUK=node.getChildElement('DESCRIPTIONUK',null).getText();
                PartStock= node.getChildElement('STOCK',null).getText();
                //Iterating the child elements
                 for(dom.XmlNode child:node.getChildElements()){
                    if(child.getName() =='CLIENTPNS'){
                    //iterating the grand child elements
                        for(dom.XmlNode gchild:child.getChildElements()){
                            if(gchild .getName() == 'CLIENTPN'){
                                //Iterating the grand grand child elements
                                for(dom.XmlNode ggchild:gchild.getChildElements()){
                                    if(ggchild .getName() == 'CLIENTPNREF'){
                                        PartClientPNREF=ggchild.getText();
                                    }
                                }//End of for loop
                            }//End of if
                        }//End of for loop
                    }//End of if
                }//End of for loop
             }//End of if condition

              if(PartDescription!=null){
            if(PartDescription.contains('\'')){
               PartDescription=PartDescription.replace('\'','\\\'');
            }
        }
        if(PartDescriptionUK!=null){
            if(PartDescriptionUK.contains('\'')){
                PartDescriptionUK=PartDescriptionUK.replace('\'','\\\'');
            }
        } 
          system.debug(PartNicomat+PartDescription);
                            AccountDetails acc = new AccountDetails(); 
                            acc.PartNicomat= PartNicomat ;
                            acc.PartDescription = PartDescription;
                            acc.PartDescriptionUK=PartDescriptionUK;
                            acc.PartStock=PartStock;
                            acc.PartClientPNREF=PartClientPNREF;
          AccountDetailsList.add(acc);
         }//End of if    
        system.debug(AccountDetailsList);
      return AccountDetailsList ;   
    }//End of method
 public class AccountDetails{
@AuraEnabled  public String PartNicomat{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled  public String PartDescription{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled  public String PartDescriptionUK{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled  public String PartStock{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled  public String PartClientPNREF{get;set;} 
    }    
}
```

webservice component :

```
<aura:component controller="quotewebservices">
    <aura:attribute name="AccountDetails" type="object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" default="D221C04DXX-0005-3310"/>
    <aura:attribute name="partnumber" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="PartDescription" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="PartStock" type="string" default=""/>
 <lightning:input label="firstName" name="Noofqli" value="{!v.firstName}" />
    <ui:inputtext value="{!v.partnumber}" label="Part number"/>
    <ui:inputtext value="{!v.PartDescription}" label="Part Description"/>
    <ui:inputtext value="{!v.PartStock}" label="PartStock"/>
    <ui:button label="Call server" press="{!c.echo}"/>

</aura:component>
```

controller :

```
({
    "echo" : function(cmp) {
       var firstName = cmp.get("v.firstName");
        var action = cmp.get("c.france");    

        action.setParams({ NicoPinFrance : firstName });

         action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if ( state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set('v.AccountDetails', response.getReturnValue());
                var acc= cmp.get("v.AccountDetails");
                //alert(acc.PartNicomat[0]);
               // alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
               cmp.set("v.partnumber", acc.PartNicomat.value());
               cmp.set("v.PartDescription",acc.PartDescription);
               cmp.set("v.PartStock",acc.PartStock)
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

I want to set wrapper class value to inputtext

> cmp.set("v.partnumber", acc.PartNicomat.value());
>   cmp.set("v.PartDescription",acc.PartDescription);
>   cmp.set("v.PartStock",acc.PartStock)

please help me how i can this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a few tweaks and it seems to be working now:

1. `<aura:attribute name="AccountDetails" type="Object[]"/>` Notice that the returned value is an array of `AccountDetails` type
2. And commented the additions to your Controller JS below.

> CLASS

```
public class QuoteWebServices {

    public static String language {get;set;}
    Public static String  NicoPinFrance{get;set;}
    public static List<AccountDetails> AccountDetailsList {get;set;}      

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static List<AccountDetails> france(string NicoPinFrance){
        // public  static List<AccountDetails> InfoWithoutAccNum() {
        String XMLString;
        AccountDetailsList = new List<AccountDetails>();
        XMLString='<RESULT><PARTNUMBER>D221C04DXX-0005-3310</PARTNUMBER><DESCRIPTION>Boîtier série\'s 0F 12 pts</DESCRIPTION><DESCRIPTIONUK>housing serie\'s OF 12pts</DESCRIPTIONUK><STOCK>43382</STOCK><CLIENTPNS></CLIENTPNS></RESULT>';
        String PartNicomat='';
        String PartDescription= '';
        String PartDescriptionUK='';
        String PartStock='';
        String PartClientPNREF='';
        //Getting the values from xml String
        system.debug(XMLString);
        if(XMLString!=null){
            Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
            doc.load(XMLString);
            dom.XmlNode node=doc.getRootElement();
            //Condition to check the responce without error 
            if(node.getChildElements()[0].getName() != 'ERROR'){
                PartNicomat=node.getChildElement('PARTNUMBER',null).getText();
                PartDescription=  node.getChildElement('DESCRIPTION',null).getText();
                PartDescriptionUK=node.getChildElement('DESCRIPTIONUK',null).getText();
                PartStock= node.getChildElement('STOCK',null).getText();
                //Iterating the child elements
                for(dom.XmlNode child:node.getChildElements()){
                    if(child.getName() =='CLIENTPNS'){
                        //iterating the grand child elements
                        for(dom.XmlNode gchild:child.getChildElements()){
                            if(gchild .getName() == 'CLIENTPN'){
                                //Iterating the grand grand child elements
                                for(dom.XmlNode ggchild:gchild.getChildElements()){
                                    if(ggchild .getName() == 'CLIENTPNREF'){
                                        PartClientPNREF=ggchild.getText();
                                    }
                                }//End of for loop
                            }//End of if
                        }//End of for loop
                    }//End of if
                }//End of for loop
            }//End of if condition

            if(PartDescription!=null){
                if(PartDescription.contains('\'')){
                    PartDescription=PartDescription.replace('\'','\\\'');
                }
            }
            if(PartDescriptionUK!=null){
                if(PartDescriptionUK.contains('\'')){
                    PartDescriptionUK=PartDescriptionUK.replace('\'','\\\'');
                }
            } 
            system.debug(PartNicomat+PartDescription);
            AccountDetails acc = new AccountDetails(); 
            acc.PartNicomat= PartNicomat ;
            acc.PartDescription = PartDescription;
            acc.PartDescriptionUK=PartDescriptionUK;
            acc.PartStock=PartStock;
            acc.PartClientPNREF=PartClientPNREF;
            AccountDetailsList.add(acc);
        }//End of if    
        system.debug(AccountDetailsList);
        //return JSON.serialize(AccountDetailsList);   
        return AccountDetailsList;   
    }//End of method

    public class AccountDetails{
        @AuraEnabled  public String PartNicomat{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled  public String PartDescription{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled  public String PartDescriptionUK{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled  public String PartStock{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled  public String PartClientPNREF{get;set;} 
    }   

}
```

> COMPONENT

```
<aura:component controller="QuoteWebServices" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="AccountDetails" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" default="D221C04DXX-0005-3310"/>
    <aura:attribute name="partnumber" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="PartDescription" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="PartStock" type="string" default=""/>

    <lightning:input label="firstName" name="Noofqli" value="{!v.firstName}" />
    <ui:inputtext value="{!v.partnumber}" label="Part number"/>
    <ui:inputtext value="{!v.PartDescription}" label="Part Description"/>
    <ui:inputtext value="{!v.PartStock}" label="PartStock"/>
    <ui:button label="Call server" press="{!c.echo}"/>

</aura:component>
```

> CONTROLLER JS

```
({
    "echo" : function(cmp) {
        var firstName = cmp.get("v.firstName");
        var action = cmp.get("c.france");    

        action.setParams({ NicoPinFrance : firstName });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if ( state === "SUCCESS") {
                //var result = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue()); //<-------------- HERE
                var result = response.getReturnValue(); //<-------------- HERE
                console.log('-----------> ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); <-------------- HERE
                cmp.set('v.AccountDetails', result); <-------------- HERE
                var acc = result[0]; <-------------- HERE
                //alert(acc.PartNicomat[0]);
                //alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
                cmp.set("v.partnumber", acc.PartNicomat); <-------------- HERE
                cmp.set("v.PartDescription", acc.PartDescription);
                cmp.set("v.PartStock", acc.PartStock)
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors) {
                        if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                            console.log("Error message: " + 
                                        errors[0].message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown error");
                    }
                }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```